# C++ program does not run if a vector has any contents

Tags: c++, stdvector

If I run this code in VScode using the g++ build settings it does not output anything. Unless I comment out "std::vector myvector = {10,20,30,40,50};" in which case it prints as expected. I found this out because using push_back() has the same effects.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> myints;
    std::cout << "0. size: " << myints.size() << '\n';
    std::vector<int> myvector = {10,20,30,40,50};
    return 0;
}
```

Setup: VScode, MSYS MinGW X64, g++ build tasks.

Haven't experienced an issue like this, if you have a better way of making a dynamic array I'll stick with that.

Comment: What version of GCC (/MinGW) are you using? Can't reproduce with GCC v6.1 through v11.2.

Comment: v11.2. -- nobody else can reproduce this either. Got a way to make a dynamic array without just implementing linked lists?

Comment: If no one can reproduce this, maybe you can just try another compiler. I tried it on v11.1.0, and it works correctly.

Comment: What on earth makes you think this is a "dynamic array"? You simply have an empty vector `myints` and then an initialized vector `myvector` -- that doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: I'm not doing anything with it yet, I just want an array that I can append stuff to. Supposedly that's a vector but the code doesn't run for me if my vectors are going to have anything inside them. Allegedly I'm supposed to be able to insert things into these or add length but that doesn't run.

Comment: Okay, the way it was phrased in the question -- had me scratching my head...

Comment: Do you do anything else besides a vector when you want a mutable array in C++? I'd be perfectly happy to just not use this type

Comment: If those four lines of code are causing you headaches, then any comparable replacement is going to be equally damaging. You have a fundamentally broken compiler. Nothing you've done in that code is anything less than kosher.

Comment: How do I fix a broken compiler then?

Comment: First, I'd compile with `-Wall` and `-Wextra` to see if anything pops up. If you get any warnings, that could give us a clue as to what on earth is going on. If you're going through an IDE, stop doing that and compile by command line, to remove that extra variable. Otherwise, burn the compiler and install it anew. gcc should not be giving you this much trouble; three commenters here (myself included) have been able to run your code flawlessly.

Comment: Figured that one out. Neither Wall or Wextra threw any extra warnings.

Comment: Try using std::endl instead of "\n". If have seen weird effect if you do not flush on program end.

Comment: Related: [C++ code wont run if a vector contains value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70994977/11082165)

Comment: I have the same issue, how do you fix this problem? Thank you.

Comment: @m4gg check my response to the related issue Brian linked. My solution basically ended up being run C++ on WSL instead of windows